# Sending PHP variables to JavaScript. Position of <script> tags?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've tried searching and couldn't find this answer since it's a bit specific.

Inside of a header.php, that is the header of the web-site, there are some scripts that are included in order for jQuery to work. Besides that, there are workscripts.js, with my written scripts. It's set like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=TEMPLATE?>js/workscripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> var query = "<?=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?>";</script>
```

In the file `workscripts.js` there is a function that switches a **cookie** on clicking a link. Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    /* View switch*/
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($.cookie("display") == null){
            $.cookie("display", "grid");
        }

        $(".grid_list").click(function(){
            var display = $(this).attr("id");
            display = (display == "grid") ? "grid" : "list";
            if(display == $.cookie("display")){
                //if the button is the same as the cookie
                return false;
            }else{
                //if the button is different
                $.cookie("display", display);
                window.location = "?" + query;
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
    /* View switch*/
});
```

It switches between views and sets it into a **cookie** basically.
**Everything works fine, my question to you is:** Why is this working, if the `workscripts.js` is first in the code, and after it we set the variable? Does JavaScript work as a whole and it doesn't matter where do you add `<script></script>`? To my understanding the positioning of `<script>`'s should be the other way around, first we set a variable **query** and send it, and after that we include `workscripts.js`?
**Another question:** Why can't we add the variable **query** directly where we include `workscripts.js`? If we include a JavaScript file to the code, we can't write anything between the tags?

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: @Quentin thank you very much for a quick reply. I'll get to that soon too, I'm just starting to learn :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in `workscripts.js` doesn't attempt to access the variable until the document *ready* event fires.

That won't fire until all the HTML has been parsed, so all the script elements will have been parsed and their scripts (although not necessarily all their functions) executed.

---

> Why can't we add the variable query directly where we include workscripts.js? If we include a JavaScript file to the code, we can't write anything between the tags?

A script element can load only a single script. If it has a src attribute it will load it from the URL. If it doesn't have a script element it will load it from inline.

Comment: One more quick question, if you don't mind. I saw the variable being added to JavaScript using single quotes, while $_SERVER element had single quotes too, like this:   
`<script type="text/javascript"> var query = '<?=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?>';</script>`  
How come the single quotes didn't cancel out each other, is it a good way to pass variable in a string?

Comment: PHP just streams everything outside `<? ?>`. And no, it isn't. See earlier comment about XSS.